# Multistage docker build: stat reports that NVIDIA file does not exist while it does

Tags: docker, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to merge two docker images.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.0-devel-ubuntu18.04 AS cuda10
FROM osrf/ros:foxy-desktop

COPY --from=cuda10 /usr/local/cuda-10.0 /usr/local/cuda-10.0
RUN cd /usr/local && ln -s cuda-10.0 cuda

COPY --from=cuda10 \
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.460.32.03 \
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.410.129 \
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.410.129 \
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-compiler.so.460.32.03 \
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so.460.32.03 \
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-allocator.so.460.32.03 \
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.460.32.03 \
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-cfg.so.460.32.03 \
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.410.129 \
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.460.32.03 \
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Build fails:

```
$ docker build . -t nvidia-ros:osrf
Step 5/7 : COPY --from=cuda10 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.460.32.03 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.410.129 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.410.129 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-compiler.so.460.32.03 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so.460.32.03 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-allocator.so.460.32.03 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.460.32.03 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-cfg.so.460.32.03 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.410.129 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.460.32.03 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
COPY failed: stat usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.460.32.03: file does not exist
```

However these files do exist:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:10.0-devel-ubuntu18.04
root@fc9c1d8ccdc2:/# ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       37 Jan 30 14:13 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.1 -> libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.460.32.03
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12129448 Aug 20  2019 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.410.129
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10516984 Dec 27 18:55 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.460.32.03
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your final test: if I pull the `nvidia/cuda:10.0-devel-ubuntu18.04` image, there are no `libnvidia*` files in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. A `find` locates these files in `/usr/local/cuda-10.0/compat/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: This file is mounted by the runtime ([docs](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-container-runtime#nvidia_driver_capabilities)), so it will not be present at the build time. You need to have a couple environment variables in your image or at the container start for the NVIDIA runtime to mount driver libraries inside. Check out the Dockerfile at the end for an example.

To investigate this I ran this command first:

```sh
docker run --rm --entrypoint="" -it nvidia/cuda:10.0-devel-ubuntu18.04 \
stat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.460.32.03
```

And got the same error:

```
stat: cannot stat '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.460.32.03': No such file or directory
```

So I went into the directory and looked with `ls`:

```
root@8c34c353bcbb:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ls libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so
ls: cannot access 'libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so': No such file or directory

root@8c34c353bcbb:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ls libn
libnccl.so         libnccl_static.a   libnpth.so.0       libnsl.so          libnss_files.so    libnss_nisplus.so  
libnccl.so.2       libnettle.so.6     libnpth.so.0.1.1   libnss_compat.so   libnss_hesiod.so   
libnccl.so.2.6.4   libnettle.so.6.4   libnsl.a           libnss_dns.so      libnss_nis.so
```

There file was missing.

Then I used the command you have shared:

```
docker run -it --rm --runtime nvidia nvidia/cuda:10.0-devel-ubuntu18.04

root@4a1602f3d5c0:/# ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       34 Jan 30 14:48 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.1 -> libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.450.66
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12129448 Aug 20  2019 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.410.129
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9947144 Sep 28 10:57 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.450.66
```

The files were there, but the version was different and it matched my NVIDIA driver version:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.66       Driver Version: 450.66       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

So it appeared to me that this file only exists when you use NVIDIA runtime to start the container. I googled this and found a confirmation [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-container-runtime#nvidia_driver_capabilities). Documentation states that you need to run a container with several environment variables for driver libs to be mounted. So I've run `env` command in an official NVIDIA container and copied every variable with `NVIDIA_` prefix into the Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.0-devel-ubuntu18.04 AS cuda10
FROM osrf/ros:foxy-desktop

COPY --from=cuda10 /usr/local/cuda-10.0 /usr/local/cuda-10.0
RUN cd /usr/local && ln -s cuda-10.0 cuda

ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=compute,utility
ENV NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA=cuda>=10.0 brand=tesla,driver>=384,driver<385 brand=tesla,driver>=410,driver<411
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
```

Running the new image with NVIDIA runtime I found the files mounted:

```
docker run --runtime nvidia --rm -it afae756457a9

root@7ebdef701231:/# stat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.450.66
  File: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.450.66
  Size: 9947144         Blocks: 19432      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 131438      Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2021-01-30 14:48:05.765015216 +0000
Modify: 2020-09-28 10:57:18.067125173 +0000
Change: 2020-09-28 10:57:18.067125173 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Is it a right way to get an image, combining outdated CUDA 10 and recent ROS2?

Comment: @wl2776 There might be a simpler way. Try to find a Dockerfile for either of these images. Then just use the other image as a base for the found Dockerfile. You'd probably have to fix a trouble or two but it should be easier than copying libraries. At least you'll have a reference. If there is no Dockerfile available for public, use `docker history <image>`. This way you can see at least some information how it was built.

Comment: Will see. NVidia published their dockerfiles in Gitlab.com. There is incompatibility, CUDA 10.0 is not supported in Ubuntu 20.04, and ROS2 is not supported on 18.04